# Docker container with non-root user deployed in Google Container Engine can not write to mounted GCE Persistent disk

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm playing with kubernetes and google container engine (GKE).

I deployed a container from this image [jupyter/all-spark-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/all-spark-notebook)

This is my replication controller :

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "datalab-notebook"
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "app": "datalab-notebook"
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "datalab-notebook",
        "labels": {
          "environment": "TEST",
          "app": "datalab-notebook"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [{
          "name": "datalab-notebook-container",
          "image": "jupyter/all-spark-notebook",
          "env": [],
          "ports": [{
            "containerPort": 8888,
            "name": "datalab-port"
          }],
          "volumeMounts": [{
            "name": "datalab-notebook-persistent-storage",
            "mountPath": "/home/jovyan/work"
          }]
        }],
        "volumes": [{
          "name": "datalab-notebook-persistent-storage",
          "gcePersistentDisk": {
            "pdName": "datalab-notebook-disk",
            "fsType": "ext4"
          }
        }]
      }
    }

  }
}
```

As you can see I mounted a Google Compute Engine Persistent Disk. My issue is that the container uses a non-root user and the mounted disk is owned by root. so my container can not write to the disk.

- **Is there a way to mount GCE persistent disks and make them read/write for containers without non-root users?**
- **Another general question : is it safe to run container with root user in Google Container Engine?**

Thank you in advance for your inputs

Comment: What would you define as safe? Because GKE gives you each VM that runs as part of the kubernetes cluster, at least it used to, not sure if that's still the case, but I believe so. So a root user container is the same as running root on your host, so if your application is fine running root normally, then you should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. The workaround I used was to run `df -h` on the host machine that the container was running on. From there I was able to find the bind point of the persistant storage. It should look something like `/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/<pd-name>`. It will also be one of the ones that has a file system that starts with `/dev` that isn't mounted to root.

Once you've found that you can run `sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/<pd-name>` from the host box, and now at least your container can use the directory, though the files will still be owned by root.

Comment: The work around worked for me. Thanks @funkymonkeymonk but I think we need to configure this kind of permission change in kubernetes config file

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I think there needs to be a better solution but until that happens this work around is pretty easy to automate into the provisioning.

Comment: Is there any PR we can track for this work being done? I'd love to put this on a watch list at work.

Comment: I accepted your answer as a temporary solution.

There is a nice volume manager called [flocker](https://clusterhq.com/flocker/introduction/), it is already supported in Kubernetes. 

The storage backends right now are AWS, OpenStack private clouds and *GCE is coming soon*. so I would go for this when the GCE become available. I hope this will abstract volume management for me

Comment: @funkymonkeymonk how do you automate changing of the permission?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the FSGroup field of the pod's security context to make GCE PDs writable by non-root users.

In this example, the gce volume will be owned by group 1234 and the container process will have 1234 in its list of supplemental groups:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1234
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    # This GCE PD must already exist.
    gcePersistentDisk:
      pdName: my-data-disk
      fsType: ext4
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I tried this solution, but it seems that the fsGroup is not supported yet in GKE. Even it is not present in the documentation, I found it just here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/proposals/volumes.md

Comment: @med I will do some digging on this for you.

Comment: It might be a day or two, I am slammed like crazy with Kube 1.2 stuff right now, but I promise that I won't forget :)

Comment: @PaulMorie I tried to use both `fsGroup` and `supplementalGroups` failing with something like `Error creating: pods "" is forbidden: SecurityContext.FSGroup is forbidden`. CoreOS, Docker 1.10.3, Kube 1.2.2. Something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: @JoaoMorais you must disable the "SecurityContextDeny" Admission Controller to set a securityContext within pod specs. See: http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/admission-controllers/#securitycontextdeny

Comment: Is the controller manager changing permissions of the volume when this pod is submitted ?  Otherwise how is 1234 more readable then any other completely random fsgroup

Comment: Jay, the volume plugins are responsible for changing the group ownership to the FSGroup.  Not all volume plugins support FSGroup - for example, it's essentially impossible to securely do chgrp to an NFS volume from the client.  1234 here is just an example - the actual value doesn't typically matter to users because its only purpose is to be uniform across all containers in the pod.  In OpenShift, as an example, we allocate an FSGroup to each namespace.  Eventually we will have this kind of allocation in k8s based on PSP.